# Не заменять кавычки на escape-последовательность

Tags: xml, веб-программирование, java

Здравствуйте. У меня возникла следующая проблема - приложение исвользует Jersey api и аннотации. Может возвращать 2 вида содержимого json, xml. Обработчик запроса промаплен как

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
```

Проблема следующая - в возвращаемом содержимом присутствует строка, содержащая кавычки '"'. В случае возврата json строка возвращается нормально, но в случае когда возвращается xml - кавычки '"' заменяются на "&quot;". Нужно это исправить. Иными словами, нужно как-то достучаться до конфига jersey и указать ему, чтоб он не искейпил кавычки, а передавал все как есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо. Проблему решил путем добавления через спринг собственного маршалера.

Answer (score 1):

Была похожая проблема, правда надо было вообще избавится от ковычек в json. решал с помощью имплементации контекстрезолвера. вот [ссылка](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.jaxb.approach.section), может поможет, точно не помню как делал, сырцы на работе лежат..